# Select count for a date range where the data is NOT IN the rest of the table

Tags: mysql, sql

This is what I have...

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT customer_number)
FROM   leads
WHERE  ( dealer_id = '75'
          OR dealer_id = '76'
          OR dealer_id = '77'
          OR dealer_id = '78'
          OR dealer_id = '70'
          OR dealer_id = '2692'
          OR dealer_id = '2693' )
       AND date BETWEEN '2013-04-01' AND '2013-04-06'
       AND customer_number NOT IN (SELECT customer_number
                                   FROM   leads
                                   WHERE  date < '2013-04-01')
```

I basically just need to do a select count where the customer_number is only counted once between the date range but also that the customer_number is not in the rest of the table.

The query above just returns zero.

Comment: maybe you are getting zero because you do not have customers that satisfy these conditions?

Comment: Also, `DISTINCT COUNT(customer_number)` should be changed to `COUNT(DISTINCT customer_number)`.  But as @akonsu says, that doesn't explain why you are seeing 0 rows.

Comment: don't you mean `SELECT Count(distinct customer_number)`?

Comment: You need to determine which of your conditions is excluding the rows you want, and it may be true that no customers meet  your conditions. But you can improve your SQL legibility by changing all of your `OR dealer_id` conditions to an `IN` operator: `WHERE dealer_id IN ('75','76','77')` and so on. Also, there is no need to have your subquery on the same table. You can simply change that to a condition `AND date >= '2013-04-01'`.

Comment: Could you provide an example or two that _should_ be in the result set? Just to see if this is coherent with your conditions...

Comment: What does this query give?  `SELECT * FROM leads WHERE date < '2013-04-01' AND customer_number IN (SELECT DISTINCT customer_number WHERE date BETWEEN '2013-04-01' AND '2013-04-06' AND dealer_id IN ('75','75','77','78','70','2692','2693')`  These are the IDs that *would* be returned by your query, except that they are being excluded by your `NOT IN` sub-query.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but I recommend using `dealer_id IN ('75', '76', ...)` instead of all those `OR` conditions. It's easier to read (IMHO) and might be optimized better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT customer_number)`

Try this query

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT customer_number)
FROM   leads
WHERE  ( dealer_id = '75'
          OR dealer_id = '76'
          OR dealer_id = '77'
          OR dealer_id = '78'
          OR dealer_id = '70'
          OR dealer_id = '2692'
          OR dealer_id = '2693' )
  AND date BETWEEN '2013-04-01' AND '2013-04-06'
  AND customer_number NOT IN (SELECT customer_number
                                     FROM   leads
                                    WHERE  date < '2013-04-01')
```

*Edit* let's put together your specification more carefully.

First, exclude all customers with stale leads at any dealership.  'Stale' means before April first.

Second, include all customers at a certain list of dealers with leads generated between the very first second of April 1st and the very first second of April 6th. Notice that this excludes almost all of April 6th if your `date` column is actually a timestamp.

Finally count the unique customers. This would seem to call for all new customers seen in a particular date range at particular dealerships.

How will you troubleshoot this? How about running the two sets of criteria separately?

```
  SELECT customer_number
    FROM leads
   WHERE customer_number NOT IN (SELECT customer_number
                                     FROM   leads
                                    WHERE  date < '2013-04-01' )
```

Do you get the list of customers you desire (the ones to include)?

Next, try this

```
SELECT customer_number
FROM   leads
WHERE  ( dealer_id = '75'
          OR dealer_id = '76'
          OR dealer_id = '77'
          OR dealer_id = '78'
          OR dealer_id = '70'
          OR dealer_id = '2692'
          OR dealer_id = '2693' )
  AND date BETWEEN '2013-04-01' AND '2013-04-06'
```

Or, better yet for performance and accurate date-time matching, this:

```
SELECT customer_number
FROM   leads
WHERE  dealer_id IN ( '75','76', '77', '78','70','2692','2693' )
  AND date >= '2013-04-01' 
  AND date < '2013-04-06'+ INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Inspect these results.  You may find your problem.

Comment: That query makes complete sense to me, but I am still seeing zero.  Which if the query is correct, means all 102 customer_number's that I find when I run the query without the NOT IN statement present are found before 2013-04-01.  Which I also know is not the case.

Comment: @Urbo425 - When you say `Which I also know is not the case`, do you have evidence of this?  The two queries you have executed *(One with the NOT IN, and one without it)* ***prove*** that the NOT IN is responsible for the rows being excluded.  I suspect that what you re failing to do *(and ask here)* is to put the `dealer_id` constraint in the sub-query.

Comment: @MatBailie Adding the dealer_id constraint in the sub-query seems to have worked.  I did a count of the customer numbers and crossed referenced a few with the rest of the table to find that some of the customer_number's were unique, which is why the return of zero wasn't making sense.

Comment: @Urbo425 - Then your stated requirements in your question are incomplete.  No-where do you state that `customer_number is not in the rest of the table` should also have *`with any of these dealer_id values`*.

Comment: @MatBailie I see how that could make a difference. hah.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: @OllieJones Thanks!  I'm still pretty new to SQL.  That really helped lay it out clearly for me.

Answer (score 1):

or maybe...

```
 SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT customer_number)
   FROM leads
   LEFT 
   JOIN leads xleads
     ON xleads.customer_number = leads.customer_number
    AND xleads.date < '2013-04-01'
  WHERE leads.dealer_id IN(75,76,77,78,70,2692,2693)
    AND leads.date BETWEEN '2013-04-01' AND '2013-04-06'
    AND xleads.customer_number IS NULL;
```

Comment: The OP's comment to another question shows this to be incomplete, because the OP's question/requirements are incomplete.  You need to apply the `dealer` constraint to the `xleads` reference too.  Or *(being that the OP hasn't clarified)* have `leads.dealer_id = xleads.dealer_id` in the JOIN's predicate.  It's all a guess, because the OP has been unclear on what is actually required.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

SELECT Count(Distinct customer_number)

Comment: Why did you put `customer_number` in brackets? THis is MySQL, not SQL-Server.